# Persisting Date Only in PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, date

I am encountering an issue while persisting data in a PostgreSQL database where I have a `birthday` field of type `date`. The problem arises when I attempt to save data as it throws an error indicating that it only accepts "UTC" time:

> Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported

However, when I try to save with UTC, it changes the `birthday` information. For instance, attempting to save `01/01/1980` results in `31/12/1979` being stored.

One workaround I have considered is using either `timestamptz` or storing the birthday information as a `string`, but I would prefer to persist only the date. Please note that `birthday` is not suitable for timestamp change.

Is there a way to save only the date without encountering this issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Postgres DDL:**

```
-- Dumped from database version 15.3
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 15.3

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;
SET default_tablespace = '';
SET default_table_access_method = heap;

CREATE TABLE public.table_users(
    last_modified timestamptz,
    birthday date,
    //Other properties
);
```

**Table setting at .Net Core:**

```
public class table_users
{
    public DateTime last_modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthday { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```

**Class setting at .Net Core:**

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```

**Action at .Net Core:**

```
    public static void AddNewUser(UserInformation input)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FlowEntities>().UseNpgsql( ... ).Options;
        using var database = new FlowEntities(options);
        var newUser = new table_users
        {
            last_modified = input.LastModified,
            birthday = input.Birthday,
            //Other properties
        };

        database.table_users.Add(newUser);
        database.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more details - table DDL, language and code fragments. The error text suggests that `birthday` field data type is not `date` but `timestamptz`.

Comment: Change the data type from timestamp to date if you don't need time or to timestamp without timezone: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772825/postgresql-alter-type-timestamp-without-time-zone-with-time-zone

Comment: @Stefanov.sm please check additional information. Seems to me that `date` is correctly defined, but I do agree that the behavior is like the case where it is set to `timestampz`.

Comment: Try making `table_users.birthday`  and `UserInformation.Birthday` of type `DateOnly` ([available since](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#introducing-the-dateonly-and-timeonly-types) .NET 6) rather than `DateTime`. This should do the trick.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm This solved the issue. Please inform as an answer so I can check it. Thanks

Comment: Done, written as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error text suggests that `birthday` field data type is not `date` but `timestamp with time zone`, but it is not the case. Make `table_users.birthday` and `UserInformation.Birthday` of type `DateOnly` (which corresponds to PostgreSQL's `date`, [available since](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#introducing-the-dateonly-and-timeonly-types) .NET 6) rather than `DateTime`. This should solve the issue.